# Python Logical Error in Loop while reading Dictionary

Tags: python, oop

I am new to python and OOPS.I am expecting my module add_book to increment if book is already present in dictionary. Please help me .Not sure why for loop is not working as expected.

https://github.com/amitsuneja/Bookstore/commit/4aefb378171ac326aacb35f355051bc0b057d3be

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not append to the list while you are still iterating it. Also, your code will append the new item for *each* item already in the list that has a different name. Instead, you should use a `for/else` loop. Here, the `else` case will only be triggered if you do not `break` from the loop.

```
for recordlist in self.mybooksinventory:
    if self.name == recordlist['name']:
        recordlist['quantity'] += 1
        break  # break from the loop
else:  # for/else, not if/else !
    self.mybooksinventory.append({'name':self.name,'stuclass':self.stuclass,'subject':self.subject,'quantity':1})
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It worked for me

Comment: please close this